# ASIHttpRequest / node.js / heroku: "Client closed connection before receiving entire response"

Tags: node.js, heroku, asihttprequest

I have an iphone app using ASIHttpRequest. The server code is on heroku in node.js

From time to time, a single request is sent from the iphone (only one trace) app but it is received twice on herokuapp (I can see twice the same request in the heroku logs).

I though at the beginning the request was requested twice because of an error in the first attempt but it's not the case as both request (the one I need and the second one I don't need) are performed on server side.

Any idea ?

Comment: Maybe it's rerequested because of connection issues?

Comment: Do you mean rerequested by the server ?

Comment: the thing is both request (the one I expect + the one I do not want) are processed on the server side.

Comment: Can you use charlesproxy or similar to see what is being sent to & from the server when this problem occurs?

Comment: Very good advice, I did not know this tool, thanks !!! Through Charles, I can see 2 requests are performed (When I expect only one). Those 2 requests have the 200 status code, but for the first one, I have the following message: "Client closed connection before receiving entire response". Both json string returned are ok though. The request's header sets the Content-Length to 0, but the response's header shows Transfer-Encoding to chuncked. Could this be linked to the chuncked stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you starting the queue with accurate progress turned on? If so, ASIHTTP makes one request (HEAD) to get the total size of the data to be downloaded, then it makes the real request. Hope that helps.

If that's not the case, try setting the persistent connection to NO, like so:

```
[asiRequest setShouldAttemptPersistentConnection:NO];
```

From my understanding, the latest version of ASIHTTPRequest defaults the persistent connection to NO. You can read more here:

https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request/issues/94

Comment: I was about to answer but you were faster :) In fact I set "[asiRequest setShouldAttemptPersistentConnection:NO];" and it's working fine now.